# Changing the order of widgets according to current page?

Tags: widgets

I would like to change the order of the widgets, for instance:

**Front-Page**:

Recent Posts

Recent Comments

**Single Post**:

Recent Comments

Recent Posts

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Widget Logic « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) with [PHP Code Widget « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) to use multiple widgets with the same function in one sidebar. Or create another sidebar and use the same widget in each; check the twentyten or twentyeleven themes for the sidebar and functions.php code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create different sidebars or the two pages.  One for front page and another for single posts?

Or in your your sidebar.php (or whichever template file is calling the widgets) you could use conditional code:

```
<?php if (is_single()) {?>
Widget html code here
<?php }?>
```